# Entity framework to object with collection, with Automapper, exception on update

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, orm, entity-framework-4, automapper

I have an EF 4.1 model, two tables are generated PERSON and ADDRESS from my database.

//This method works

```
public void Update(IPerson person)
{
    var personDb = _dataContext.PERSON.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ID == person.Id);
    Mapper.Map<Person, PERSON>((Person)person, personDb);
    _dataContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

But when I remove the .Ignore() in Automapper mapping, I get this exception :

*The EntityCollection could not be initialized because the relationship manager for the object to which the EntityCollection belongs is already attached to an ObjectContext. The InitializeRelatedCollection method should only be called to initialize a new EntityCollection during deserialization of an object graph.*

I'd like when I added an new address to the existing addresses save the person and address.

Any idea ?

Thanks,

```
public void AutomapperInit()
{
    Mapper.CreateMap<Person, PERSON>()
        .ForMember(x => x.ADDRESS, opt => opt.Ignore());
    Mapper.CreateMap<PERSON, Person>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Address, option => option.MapFrom(src => src.ADDRESS.Select(address => Mapper.Map<ADDRESS, Address>(address)).ToList()));
    Mapper.CreateMap<Address, ADDRESS>();
    Mapper.CreateMap<ADDRESS, Address>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Rue, option => option.MapFrom(src => src.STREET));
}

public interface IPerson
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string FirstName { get; set; }
    string LastName { get; set; }
    ICollection<IAddress> Address { get; set; }
}

public interface IAddress
{
    string Rue { get; set; }
    string Number { get; set; }
    int PersonId { get; set; }
}

class Person : IPerson
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<IAddress> Address { get; set; }
}

 class Address : IAddress
{
    public string Rue { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does

```
var personDb = Mapper.Map<Person, PERSON>((Person)person, personDb); 
_dataContext.Attach(personDb);
_dataContext.SaveChanges();
```

give the results you expect, or am I misinterpreting your question?

Comment: it's not personDB the problem, it's the collection conencted to personDb